# ArrowJS reactive chaining

Tags: javascript, arrowjs

I'm using [ArrowJS](https://www.arrow-js.com/) to learn about reactivity, and I have hit a basic issue that I don't understand.

```
let data = reactive({
    price: 0,
    quantity: 1,
    total: 0,
});

watch(() => data.total = data.price * data.quantity);

html`Total: ${() => data.total}`(document.getElementById('output'));
```

I am expecting the change of either *data.price* or *data.quantity* to update *data.total*, and then that change in *data.total* to update the DOM.

*data.total* changes correctly, but the DOM remains displaying 0.

However, if I change the last line to the following, it does work correctly:

```
html`Total: ${() => data.price * data.quantity}`(document.getElementById('output'));
```

My questions is, should this sort of chaining work, or am I misunderstanding something?

---

Here is the full HTML code.
I am adjusting the price with `data.price = 10` from the console.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="module">
      import { reactive, watch, html } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/@arrow-js/core';

      let data = reactive({
        price: 0,
        quantity: 1,
        total: 0,
      });

      watch(() => data.total = data.price * data.quantity);

      html`Total: ${() => data.total}`(document.getElementById('output'));

      // To allow access from console
      window.data = data;
    </script>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div id="output"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where exactly are you changing any of the properties of `data`?

Comment: @code I'm doing it from the console - **data.price = 10;**

Comment: @code I just tried linking it to an input box and both *data.price* and *data.total* reflect the change, but the DOM does not

Comment: @threenplusone can you please share that example? You can add a runnable example to your question by clicking [edit] and creating a [code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: @NickParsons I have added the full HTML code now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After experimenting and digging inside [the source code](https://github.com/justin-schroeder/arrow-js/blob/master/src/index.ts), I conclude that you cannot mutate the reactive object reactively inside a `watch` callback.

```js
const [price, quantity, output] = ["price", "quantity", "output"].map(document.getElementById.bind(document));

(async () => {
  const { reactive, watch, html } = await import("https://cdn.skypack.dev/@arrow-js/core");
  let data = reactive({
    price: 0,
    quantity: 0,
    total: 0,
  });

  watch(() => {
    data.total = data.price * data.quantity; // this has no effect reactively
    console.log(data.total);
  });

  price.addEventListener("input", () => data.price = +price.value);
  quantity.addEventListener("input", () => data.quantity = +quantity.value);
  
  html`Total: ${() => data.total}`(output);
})()
```

```html
<input id="price" placeholder="price" type="number" />
<input id="quantity" placeholder="quantity" type="number" />
<div id="output"></div>
```

I can't exactly figure out *where* in the code disables this, but I suspect it may have something to do with the internal `queue` function; if it was intentional, it's apparently to prevent infinite re-renders...

So basically, what you're *supposed* to do is mutate the variables in an event-driven manner. So like what worked for you in the beginning:

```js
(async () => {
  const { reactive, watch, html } = await import("https://cdn.skypack.dev/@arrow-js/core");
  let data = reactive({
    price: 0,
    quantity: 0,
    total: 0,
  });
  
  const total = () => data.price * data.quantity;
  
  html`
    <input @input="${e => data.price = e.target.value}" placeholder="price" type="number" />
    <input @input="${e => data.quantity = e.target.value}" placeholder="quantity" type="number" />
    Total: ${total}
  `(document.getElementById("root"));
})();
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That sort of makes sense since `total` is a calculated field, so I shouldn't be storing it in the reactive object anyway

Comment: @threenplusone exactly. I guess that's just how it works.